# Java - Get substring from 2nd last occurrence of a character in string

Tags: java, string, substring, indices, lastindexof

My input: `"professions/medical/doctor/"`

My desired output: `"doctor"`

I have the following solution but it is not a one-liner:

```
String v = "professions/medical/doctor/";
String v1 = v.substring(0, v.length() - 1);
String v2 = v1.substring(v1.lastIndexOf("/")+1, v1.length());
System.out.println(v2);
```

How can I achieve the same in a one-liner?

Comment: You can use a regex to achieve the same. Something like \/\w+\/$ would give you the match.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use `String#split` here (requiring either a one or two line solution):

```
String v = "professions/medical/doctor/";
String[] parts = v.split("/");
String v2 = parts[parts.length-1];
System.out.println(v2);
```

If you know that you want the third component, then you may just use:

```
System.out.println(v.split("/")[2]);
```

For a true one-liner, `String#replaceAll` might work:

```
String v = "professions/medical/doctor/";
String v2 = v.replaceAll(".*/([^/]+).*", "$1");
System.out.println(v2);
```

Comment: I like the split technique here. Split into segments and pull out which one you want.

Comment: I like split too.  Banana split - more so.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Now just stop that!  You're making me hungry.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lastIndexOf(str, fromIndex)` variant:

```
String v2 = v.substring(v.lastIndexOf('/', v.length() - 2) + 1, v.length() - 1);
```

Comment: I get this error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 @iluxa

Comment: My bad, misunderstood the `fromIndex`. Updated the answer, try that